# How did 'arching' come into use as a verb meaning 'to thwart'?

Tags: etymology, verbs, slang, neologisms

I have seen the word 'arch' used as a verb in the context of a villain causing trouble for a hero, or a hero thwarting a villain.  It is also used when a villain is actively trying to become a hero's primary nemesis.  I've only seen it in comedic or informal settings, or when talking about a hero/villain relationship.  It probably sprang from 'arch-enemy', but I'm trying to find where and when this phrasing was first used.  Can this be sourced to a particular work?  How long has this usage been around?

Comment: ([Arches a mystified look](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=6rVOwpr0oAUC&pg=PT138&dq=%22arched+him%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vP92UvzBKIW10QXpt4CIDw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22arched%20him%22&f=false)). I've not seen this usage. Can you link to any examples?

Comment: "I'm Trying to arch here, this is how it's done!" -The Monarch, Venture Brothers, episode 36.  The Monarch is a villain, explaining to the heroes why he's doing what he's doing.  It's also used in a synopsis of the episode [here] (http://venturefans.org/vbwiki/The_Lepidopterists).

Comment: I wouldn't say the writer there is a "compentent native speaker". For example, *"The duo ... quickly dispose of the captain via a tranquilizer dart, which incidentally **forms an addiction** for the captain."* looks like very strange phrasing to me, and the guy certainly can't spell. Anyway, unless you can find several other similar instances, I think most likely you're looking at one [clumsy, imho) writer being "creative" with his usage. Sometimes he uses "arch" as a noun (short for "arch-enemy", obviously). Other times it's just a verb meaning "play the role of an arch-enemy")...

Comment: ...such devices (using an adjective as a verb or noun) are common in ephemeral/casual contexts. For most native speakers, the meaning will be clear *in context*, but it would be stretching a point to say it's "English" as might be recorded by dictionaries and grammar books.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am aware the usage is not '"English" as it might be recorded by dictionaries and grammar books', hence the tagging of my question with 'slang' and 'neologisms'. I have heard the word used in person, but was having trouble finding it in a more formal use online.  I know the meaning, I was looking for the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the verb *to arch* (to be an arch-enemy or do arch-enemy things against a hero) is from *The Venture Bros.* cartoon and mostly restricted to the programme and its fans.

The top entry on [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=arCH&defid=6164409) is:

> **1. arCH**
>
> arch, to arch /ahrCH/
>   verb transitive
>
> to desire to cause harm, foil plans, and generally create aggression against targeted individuals or groups, used esp. with supervillains
>
> *We go around "arching" people at work.*
>
> [arch] [venture bro] [monarch] [adult swim] [rusty]
>
> by Dr Girlfriend October 26, 2011
>   23 up, 14 down

You'll notice the tags include "venture bro", so it appears to be only used in reference to the *The Venture Bros.* cartoon. The person who added it used a username, [Dr. Girlfriend](http://venturebrothers.wikia.com/wiki/Dr._Mrs._The_Monarch), which is an alias of the character Dr. Mrs. The Monarch in the same cartoon.

The Monarch used the verb in [episode 36, "The Lepidopterists"](http://venturefans.org/vbwiki/The_Lepidopterists/Quotes) of *The Venture Bros.* (original airdate: Aug 3, 2008):

> I'm trying to **arch** here, this is how it's done!

It was also used in [episode 30](http://venturefans.org/vbwiki/Home_Is_Where_the_Hate_Is/Quotes) (June 22, 2008):

> Sgt. Hatred - The one thing I've learned is there's no good reason on God's green earth that **arching** has to be a completely unpleasant experience for either of us.

In [Episode 34](http://venturefans.org/vbwiki/Tears_of_a_Sea_Cow/Quotes) (July 20, 2008):

> HENCHMAN 24
>   He went **arching?** Without us?
>
> HENCHMAN 21
>   Ow! Oh! We don't get to do anything! I'm like this close to **arching** the paperboy!

And [Episode 10](http://venturefans.org/vbwiki/Tag-Sale_--_You%27re_it!/Transcript) (October 9, 2004):

> Dr. Girlfriend: I'm flattered boys, but I'm with the Monarch now. And you know he's been **arching** Dr. Venture

The verb is used a lot by fans in [The Archer Bros. wiki](http://venturefans.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3aSearch&search=arching&go=Go).

Comment: Thanks. I first heard the word used by Aureli Voltaire, describing his relationship to Doc Hammer (one of the Venture Bros. creators). I had assumed the usage started with the Venture Bros, but wanted to know if there had been an earlier usage I missed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that arching in this context means "to thwart"; I think that "to arch" is a verb whose usage is mostly constrained to the Venture Bros., where it refers to the organized practice of comicbook-style rivalry characterized in the relationship between a hero and her **arch** -nemesis.

The Monarch arches, or plays archnemesis to, Dr. Venture.